# Laravel array in mustache template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mustache.php

This is my Controller:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

public $layout = 'default';

public function index()
{
    $page = Page::find(1);
    $this->layout->page_title = $page->page_title;


    $allPages = Page::lists('title');
    // Give the page it's needed content
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'pages.home', array(
        'pageHeading' => 'Rendered with Mustache.php',
        'pageContent' => $allPages
    ));   
}

}
```

I have this master template called `default.blade.php` and a child page template called `home.mustashe`.

Problem is, I want to use the array containing all my page titles in the `home.mustache` template. how do add my array into the `home.mustache` template?

The code as it is now gives me following error: `Array to string conversion`

The Mustache Package i use is: [Link to mustache package](https://github.com/conarwelsh/mustache-l4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means, quite literally, "You're trying to display an array as a string" ... which you haven't provided enough context do debug completely, but I'd guess means you're setting `pageContent` as an array of values, then calling `{{ pageContent }}` in a template.

Either convert your array to a string yourself:

```
implode(', ',  $allPages)
```

… or do something array-like with `pageContent` inside the template:

```
{{# pageContent }}<li>{{ . }}</li>{{/ pageContent }}
```

Comment: What do you need then? :) and I'm still unsure how to serve the array to the template.

Answer (score 0):

The docs on your Mustache package say arrays get handled as follows:

```
{{#posts}}
    {{> posts._post}}
{{/posts}}
```

Comment: I know that, but how do I add the array, like I do with the strings, from my controller?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work, Laravel gives me the following error: Array to string conversion.. I really don't know what to do now. :/